# Exibir uma imagem se o valor "7" estiver na row "Codigos"

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mysqli, if

agradeço a ajuda que irão me oferecer. Eu tentei muitas coisas, mas agora não estou avançando em nada. Consegui colocar esse código mas ele não me mostra nenhuma imagem.

Lá no topo no meu

```
 $results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

E lá na tabela vem assim:

```
  <?php foreach( $results as $row ){
    if($row['Codigos'] == 7 && $row['Maquinas'] == 5) {
 echo '<img src="/images/'.$photo->t1.png.'"/>';
    }
    ?>
```

Resumindo... terei uma tabela com várias possibilidades, serão 3 colunas na tabela e as imagens irão trocar a cada X minutos e caso o valor mude no banco de dados, então mudará a imagem dentro da tabela também.

Obrigado a todos novamente!

Comment: E qual o erro ?

Comment: `var_dump($row['Codigos'])` dá o que ? e `var_dump($row['Maquinas'])` ?

Comment: @ViniciusShiguemori Obrigado por ajudar, então... não aparece nada. Se eu coloco somente informações da view ela aparece, mas tentando usar esse código com a imagem não vai...

Comment: @Isac Quais valores eles trazem? Então, existe um gateway instalado em um local que me traz informações através de um IP. São números que atualizam a cada X minutos. Sempre números...

Comment: ta faltando fechar o `foreach`

Comment: Só tem um numero ou tem o ip todo separado por `.` ? Tá como `string` ou como `int` ? Todos esses tipos de detalhes interessam e podem ter diferença para o que está a tentar fazer

Comment: @Isac Na verdade eu possuo uma tabela separada que traz essas informações, por isso montei uma view que traz somente os resultados. Resumindo, então tenho uma view somente para o que eu preciso "puxar". Caso haja o valor 2 na coluna "x" e o valor 3 na coluna "y" então mostra a imagem. Deu para entender?

Comment: Se você adicionar alguma imagem manualmente, ela aparece?

Comment: @MárcioCristian Obrigado por ajuda :) Sim, eu tentei inserir normalmente e foi... 
<td class="tg-031e"><img src="images/TELA-MONITOR-USAR_01.png" alt=""></td>

Comment: Se você puder, edite e cole um output da variável $photo, tenta usar o var_dump.